# I need to test a set of Jackpot results. I need a function which returns true if all results are identical, and false if they are different

Tags: javascript, function, reduce

Here is what I have so far:

- I understand the syntax
- I am struggling to understand the logic

```js
const testJackpot = result => {
  if (!result.length) 
    return true;
    
  return result.reduce((a, b) => {
    return (a === b) ? a : (!b);
  }) === result[0];
}

console.log(testJackpot(["@", "@", "@", "@"]))
```

The code seems to work, however, I don't understand exactly how.

What is the reason for the following statement:

```js
if (!result.length) 
  return true;
```

And I need help understanding how the `.reduce()` method is operating here.

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is the wron tool, because it iterates all elements of the array and you get a result which needs a check at the and, too.

---

You could take [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead and check each element against the first one.

This approach returns `true` for an empty array, as desired.

```js
const testJackpot = array => array.every((v, _, a) => v === a[0]);

console.log(testJackpot([]));
console.log(testJackpot(["@", "@", "@", "@"]));
console.log(testJackpot(["@", "@", "", "@"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the "every" method built into javascript arrays.

```
["@", "@", "@", "@"].every(item => item === "@")
```

See more here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other two answers, using `.every()` is a much better approach.
But, to answer your actual question,

```
if(!result.length)
return true;
```

Array.length returns falsey if the array is empty, i.e length zero equates to false.
The check returns true.

You can think of `.reduce()` as a for-loop.

```
return result.reduce((a, b) => {
  return (a === b) ? a : (!b);
}) === result[0];
```

the 'a' parameter is the accumulator/holder and first iteration value, the 'b' is the next iteration value
so what's happening here is that if the iteration value 'b' matches 'a' then 'a' is returned to the accumulator/holder, if not b is returned. then after all items have been iterated the code checks if the returned value (the accumulator/holder - or in this case 'a') matches the first item in the array. If all the items match the 'a' will never change, but as soon as an item that doesn't match is found, 'a' will change and will no longer match the first item.

I hope this helps shed some light on what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of SET object to find unique values in an array.

```
function testJackpot(arr) {
    const set1 = new Set();

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        set1.add(arr[i])
    }
    if (set1.size == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


console.log(testJackpot(["@", "@", "@", "@"]))
```